# DriveApp.getUrl returning "Cannot find function getUrl in object Drive"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is what I'm using, I've also tried switching DriveApp for SpreadsheetApp with the same error. Any ideas?

```
    var spreadsheetname = playerarray[i] + " Prisoner's Dilemma Individual Sheet";
    var newspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(spreadsheetname);
    spreadsheetlinks.push(DriveApp.getUrl(newspreadsheet));
    spreadsheetlinks.push(DriveApp.getId(newspreadsheet));
```

Comment: Like the error says, the function `getUrl` is not available in `DriveApp`. What made you think it was available?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl()    The reference documentation

Comment: Is there a way to do this then with a different command?

Comment: As you can see from the reference documentation, `getUrl` is a function available on the class `file`. `DriveApp` is not `file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, the function `getUrl` is not available in `DriveApp`.  It is available on classes [`file`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl()) and [`Spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl). Fortunately, [`SpreadsheetApp.create`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) returns a `spreadsheet`.

```
var spreadsheetname/* type: string*/ = playerarray[i] + " Prisoner's Dilemma Individual Sheet";
var newspreadsheet /* type: spreadsheet*/= SpreadsheetApp.create(spreadsheetname);

/*pushing string type into array type*/
spreadsheetlinks.push(newspreadsheet.getUrl());//getUrl available on spreadsheet type
```